# What is the non-pointer equivalent of NULL?

Tags: c++, null

Apologies for my improper terminology.

I have a piece of code that returns a NULL pointer if an entry doesn't exist:

```
ObjectType * MyClass::FindObjectType( const char * objectTypeName )
{
    if ( objectTypeMap.find( objectTypeName ) == objectTypeMap.end() )
    {
        Msg( "\n[C++ ERROR] No object type: %s", objectTypeName );
        return NULL;
    }
    else
        return &objectTypeMap[ objectTypeName ];
}
```

I want to do the same thing but this time returning an object instead of just a pointer. The following code isn't giving me any compiler errors (which surprises me):

```
ObjectType MyClass::FindObjectType( const char * objectTypeName )
{
    if ( objectTypeMap.find( objectTypeName ) == objectTypeMap.end() )
    {
        Msg( "\n[C++ ERROR] No object type: %s", objectTypeName );
    }
    else
        return objectTypeMap[ objectTypeName ];
}
```

With the pointer I can check if the entry wasn't found like so:

```
if ( FindObjectType( objectType ) == NULL )
    //Do something
```

How do I perform the equivalent check with the object being returned?

Comment: `boost::optional<ObjectType>` or an exception.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is no language-level equivalent for objects.

One option is to create a "sentinel" object that is guaranteed to compare unequal to any "real" object, and return that:

```
class ObjectType {
public:
    static const ObjectType null;

    bool operator==(const ObjectType &rhs) const { /* need an appropriate comparison test */ }

    ...
};

ObjectType ObjectType::null(/* something unique */);


...

ObjectType foo(const char *objectTypeName) {
    if (cond) {
        return objectTypeMap[objectTypeName];
    } else {
        return ObjectType::null;
    }
}


...

if (foo(objectType) == ObjectType::null) {
    std::cout << "Returned the null object\n";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could you demonstrate how this is done?

Answer (score 5):

The following code is not giving an error because the Standard is very conservative.

Some code structures are extremely convoluted and the compiler cannot know whether the end of the function may be reached or not. Therefore the Standard says that the compiler does not have to prove that the function correctly return a value...

**However** the Standard does say that should a function ends normally (no exception) without having returned a value, then **Undefined Behavior** is invoked (ie, anything can happen, likely a crash). Most compilers thus have a *warning* for such situation, for gcc and Clang you can use `-Wreturn`.

---

Now, the principle of nullity or *sentinel values* is not new, and a null pointer is just *one* incarnation (among many).

If it does not make sense for your object to be nullable (it rarely does but can be an expedient) then you have 2 alternatives:

- `throw` an exception to signal the error
- return a wrapper class (such as `boost::optional<ObjectType>`) which may be null

In this condition, since it is expected that `Find` may not find anything, I would advise the latter in general.

Usage is simple:

```
boost::optional<ObjectType> MyClass::FindObjectType(char const* objectTypeName )
{
    if ( objectTypeMap.find( objectTypeName ) == objectTypeMap.end() ) {
        // do not print anything, it is up to the caller to decide what to do
        return boost::none;
    }

    return objectTypeMap[ objectTypeName ];
}
```

And then the caller writes:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    if (boost::optional<ObjectType> o = MyClass::FindObject(argv[1])) {
        o->foo();

        return 0;
    }

    Msg( "\n[C++ ERROR] No object type: %s", argv[1]);
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Is `boost::none` convertible to `false`?

Comment: @Nawaz: I don't think so... and I don't understand why you ask actually.

Comment: @Nawaz: `boost::optional<T>` can be used in boolean expressions, relying on a variant of the [safe bool idiom](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Safe_bool). So you can write `if (myOptional)` to test the presence of the value (or `if (!myOptional)` to test its absence).

Comment: @Nawaz: `boost::none`, on the other hand, is an instance of `boost::none_t`, and is simply used as a tag to construct an unitialized instance of `optional`. There is no reason to make `none_t` convertible to `bool`, in fact it is probably just an empty struct. EDIT: hum, it is in fact [a bit more complicated](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/boost/none_t.hpp) than a simple empty struct (I'm not sure why, though).

Comment: @MatthieuM.: I asked that because you have used `FindObject` in `if`, implies `boost::none` can convert into `false`.

Comment: @Nawaz: no, I use `boost::optional<ObjectType>` in `if`, implying that `boost::optional<T>` may convert to `bool`.

Comment: @MatthieuM.: And I thought, the type of `boost::none` is `boost::optional<T>`.

Comment: @Nawaz: ah sorry, `boost::none` is of type `boost::none_t`, `boost::optional<T>` has several constructors (generally dependent on `T`) plus a constructor `optional(none_t)` which just initializes it to the "null" state.

Answer (score 2):

## C++17 update

C++17 introduces `std::optional` as part of the standard library, the closest thing to a null object in the language, analogous to "Maybe" in other programming languages. It works much like `boost::optional` described in [the previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10931200/14141690). One of the use cases it is intended to solve is returning an optional value from a function.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <optional> // Defines std::optional

std::optional<int> f(bool test) {
    if (test) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return std::optional<int>();
    }
}

int main()
{
    auto ret = f(true);
    
    // std::optional can be used as a bool
    if (ret) {
        std::cout << "Value for first test: " << ret.value() << '\n';
    } else {
        std::cout << "Value for first test: " << 0 << '\n';
    }
    
    std::cout << "Value for second test: " << (f(true)).value_or(0) << '\n';
    std::cout << "Value for third test: " << (f(false)).value_or(0) << '\n';
    
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Value for first test: 1
Value for second test: 1
Value for third test: 0
```